# custom UIPickerView with two date rows

Tags: ios

I need to make something like http://alicia.mobile9.com/download/as/ios/04/16/416837150/screen7.jpg. Is there a ready library for such UI tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is UIKit and the class is `UIPickerView`. Setup the picker view to have two components and provide the needed titles for each row by implementing the appropriate `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods. It's actually very simple.